# Getting Null pointer exception when returning from mysql query

Tags: java, mysql, spring

## Controller class call:

```
List<FOO> fooList   = fooDao.getFooList(String.valueOf(branchId),customerId,String.valueOf(systemIndex));
```

## Dao class method that gets invoked:

```
public List<FOO> getFooList(String index_branch,String index_cust,String index_sys) 
{
   // Object[] helo= new Object[10];
   System.out.println("branchId -> " +index_branch+ "customerId -> " +index_cust+ " systemId -> " +index_sys);
   return db.query("select * from tb_foo where branch=? and customer=? and system=?",new RowMapper<FOO>() {
   @Override
   public FOO mapRow(ResultSet rs, int i) throws SQLException {
        FOO foo = new FOO();
        foo.setPi(rs.getInt("foo_pi"));
        foo.setIndex(rs.getInt("foo_index"));
        foo.setFooName(rs.getString("foo_name"));
        foo.setFooValue(""+rs.getInt("foo_value"));
        return foo; 
        }
    },index_branch,index_cust,index_sys);

}
```

Query when provided using `CommandLine` client returns a list of values from database, however `RowMapper` is not returning. I checked if fooDao was returning null, but it wasn't. Getting Null pointer exception on line return `db.query(...);`

Comment: How did you inject `db` ? print the stacktrace as well !!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your question actually is but,

Place a breakpoint at

```
db.query(...);
```

and check that db is not null